# Error when using vmware on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: virtualization, vmware

We're currently going to install Ubuntu on laptops and use VMWare.

However, an error has occurred, such as in the picture, and VMWare cannot be used by any means.

Fist image:

[image]

Second image:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to describe how you installed VMware and to include the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; sudo modprobe vmmon || sudo dmesg | tail -n 50`? Thanks.

Comment: The installation method was discovered and continued.  lsb_release -a : Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 17.10
Release: 17.10
Codename: artful ,   uname -a : Linux Ubuntu-Desktop 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vmmon': Required key not available
[    2.864399] thermal thermal_zone5: failed to read out thermal zone (-5)
[    2.865599] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.920307] audit: type=1400 audit(1519005575.079:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=597 comm="apparmor_parser"

Comment: **Again, could you please *[edit]* your post,** when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.